Neovim return to previous buffer on close
Let's say i open plugin "page" (e.g. email client) to check something. After i'm done, i want <C-W>q to close the buffer and return me to the previous buffer used. New buffer acted like "overlay", in a sense. Is it possible without overriding the meaning of the <C-W>q and without using other keymaps to quit the plugin's buffer?

sooo use :bd? or maybe ctrl-w+c ?

@KamilCuk :bd works, thanks
